# How to filter images and respective captions based on buttons and input field values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an image gallery which will have 2 types of filters

1. Based on navigation
2. Based on the content mentioned in the input box.

When I click on a navigation button based on the clicks images and respective caption to be filtered and I write anything on the input field it should drill down further.

Request you to please help to stream line the below code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, div, p, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("mysrch");
  li = div.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection© {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf© > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Center website */

.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px -16px;
}


/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */

.row,
.row>.column {
  padding: 8px;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 19.99%;
  display: none;
  /* Hide all elements by default */
}


/* Clear floats after rows */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Content */

.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */

.show {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <h1>MYLOGO.COM</h1>
  <hr>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Content" title="Search">
  <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>

  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('nature')"> Nature</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('people')"> People</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
  <div class="row mysrch">
    <div class="column nature">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="Growth.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Mountains</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column cars">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="CogWheel.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Lights</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column cars">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="Growth.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Forest</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column cars">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="CogWheel.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Retro</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column cars">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="Growth.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Fast</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column people">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="CogWheel.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Classic</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column people">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="Offer.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Girl</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column people">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="Offer.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Man</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column people">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="Offer.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
        <h4>Woman</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My sincere apologies due to lack of knowledge. Thank you very much for guiding me to the right path